# Why is ClipGrab.pro not opening?

Tags: software-installation, youtube, downloaders

I am trying to open Clipgrab but clipgrab.pro not open with run software i can't understand what I missed:

[image]

I also tried to run using:

```
qmake clipgrab.pro && make
```

but got no response. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: What is Clipgrab? How did you installed it?

Comment: https://clipgrab.org/ It's a youtube downloader. it is downloading as a tar.gz archive this is its extract view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile and use ClipGrab you need to do the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download.clipgrab.org/clipgrab-3.8.0.tar.gz
tar -xf clipgrab-3.8.0.tar.gz
cd clipgrab-3.8.0
```

then get all needed dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qt5-default qtbase5-dev qtwebengine5-dev
```

then compile it

```
qmake clipgrab.pro && make
```

and use it

```
./clipgrab
```

---

Another option is to get ClipGrab from [its PPA](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```